# How to resolve TypeError: 'str' object is not callable : Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am new to pandas. I am trying below code, but error.
What would be the correct syntax for `x(df['old_score'])` in the `lambda`?

**code**:

```
df['new_score'] = df['score'].apply(lambda x : x(df['old_score']) if x == 'Low' else x)
```

**Expected_output**:
[Expected_Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf7WL.png)

**Error**:
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: in your lambda `x` is a string (each value in the `'score'` column) and you've written `x(df['old_score'])`.

Comment: how to resolve this ?